# Google Drive API upload create temporary file in the server

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

Does Google Drive API upload file to my drive will create a temporary file on my server?

I tried to have an old fashion PHP file upload form before, and I delete the file after use/abort. However, for every upload, PHP *automatically* creates a temporary file in my server, and this file is often being marked with virus.

I wanted to try Google Drive API to upload directly to my drive, because google has a better virus defender and the file won't be stored on my server.

However, if Google Drive API creates a temp file anyway, my server's storage is still in danger. Is there anyway to safely upload that won't contaminate my server at all?

Comment: Try to check these different options on how to [upload a files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) if it is applicable in your case. You will learn here on how to use the simple upload, multipart upload and resumable upload. This page also consist of examples codes that show how to upload an image using the different client libraries. Just check the Drive API documentation to know all the possible way that you can do with it. For more information, check this [page](https://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/) if it can help you.

Comment: Also, one way to avoid contaminating the server is to further review the option to sync specific files and folders as mentioned in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/GWD9CC1djEg).

Comment: Hello, Thank you for respond, the problem is before the file even made to google drive, php $_post file will create a temporary file in the tmp folder, and this folder is constantly flagged with virus file detection(anti-virus detects it before the code has a chance to delete them). I was hoping there would be a way to get file to google drive without create a temp file in my server at all. Thank you